# VBA: Generating Data that mimics specific parameters (Avg, StdDev..etc)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have modified a VBA array function given to me here: [Excel Generate Normalized Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633024/excel-generate-normalized-data)

That question will explain what I am after.

---

Download the excel I am using to completely understand:

http://www.mediafire.com/?smq5tl9poitdacc

---

I am using the following data (The left side are values I enter for the data to be based upon, the right side is the results of the generated data):

[image]

As you can see, the % Diff is very good for Avg Click, but Click/Time is off when there is a high Day StdDev (Day +/-). The difference when there is a low Day Stddev is close to 0.

I think this is because the var **NoClickDaysPerClick_Running_Avg** becomes inaccurate because the **NoClickDays_Total** (Which is used indirectly to determine the running avg) is "guessed" at the start, and needs to be reassessed each click because the high StdDev adds randomness and the original "guess" becomes more and more inaccurate.

I am not sure if this is the problem, or if it is how I can even solve it.

I am just looking for advice on the best way to do what it is I want. I am not sure why the stdDev are so far off either, but thats not a big deal. I'd rather have a more accurate Click/Time than anything else- reguardless what the Day StdDev is.

---

here is the function in my VBA:

```
Function ClickSpacer(Total_Days As Long, ClicksPerDay_Desired_Avg As Double, Clicks_Desired_Deviation As Double, Clicks_Min As Integer, Clicks_Max As Integer, TotalClicksOverTotalDays_Desired_Avg As Double, NoClickDays_Desired_Deviation As Double, NoClickDays_Min As Integer, NoClickDays_Max As Integer)


    Dim Day_Array() As Integer
    ReDim Day_Array(1 To Total_Days, 1 To 1)

    Dim NumDaysToGetClicks As Double
    Dim ClickOffset As Long

    Dim Clicks_Total As Long
    Dim Clicks_SoFar As Long
    Dim Clicks_Remaining As Long


    Dim NoClickDaysPerClick_Desired_Avg As Double





    ' Number of clicks that are needed to Achieved desired Avg of clicks over time
    Clicks_Total = Round(Total_Days * TotalClicksOverTotalDays_Desired_Avg, 0)

    ' Number of days in which the user has to click atleast once to achieve desired Avg. clicks per day
    NumDaysToGetClicks = Round(Clicks_Total / ClicksPerDay_Desired_Avg, 0)

    ' The number of non-click days in order fill out the total days
    NoClickDays_Total = Round(Total_Days - NumDaysToGetClicks, 0)





    ' The guessimated average of non-click days per click to fill out total non-click days
    ' This is never used, just used for comparsion of the running Avg
    NoClickDaysPerClick_Desired_Avg = NoClickDays_Total / NumDaysToGetClicks





    'This variable is here to achieved closer results to the desired StdDev.
    'a higher multiplyer will not limit the deviation but just give an average deviation
    'For example, if the Average was 3 with a +/- 2, then with a StdDevMulti of 1
    'ALL numbers will be 1 (3-2) through 5  (3+2) with an avg of 3 and stddev of 2, the numbers will NEVER exceed the StdDev.
    'With a StdDevMulti of 2, the numbers will be 0 through 6, but should still have an
    'Avg deviation of 2.
    StdDevMulti = 1

    NoClickDays_Desired_Deviation = NoClickDays_Desired_Deviation * StdDevMulti
    Clicks_Desired_Deviation = Clicks_Desired_Deviation * StdDevMulti


    'Set the obvious defaults
    ClickedDaysSoFar = 0
    Clicks_SoFar = 0
    NoClickDays_SoFar = 0

    'Give the ClickOffset a starting value
    ClickOffset = NoClickDaysPerClick_Desired_Avg

    Do

        'used to find the "running" average of days not clicked
        NoClickDays_Remaining = NoClickDays_Total - NoClickDays_SoFar

        'used to find the "running" average of clicks per day
        Clicks_Remaining = (Clicks_Total - Clicks_SoFar)

        'used in both "running" averages mentioned above and also will
        'mark the end of the while loop.
        RemainingClickedDays = (NumDaysToGetClicks - ClickedDaysSoFar)


        ' Find what the average num. click should be based on the remaining
        ' and then apply the deviation. Only accept a click below its max
        ' above its min.
        Do

            ' Generate a random number between -1 and 1
            SignChanger = Rnd() - Rnd()

            ' Apply the randomized StdDev
            Clicks_Deviation = Clicks_Desired_Deviation * SignChanger

            'Figure out the "running" average
            ClicksPerDay_Running_Avg = Clicks_Remaining / RemainingClickedDays

            'Figure out a click value and round to the nearest whole number
            Generated_Clicks = Round(ClicksPerDay_Running_Avg + Clicks_Deviation, 0)

        ' Make sure it meets the requirements, if not, try again
        Loop While Generated_Clicks < Clicks_Min Or Generated_Clicks > Clicks_Max


        ' Set the click value to the spaced-out array index
        Day_Array(ClickOffset, 1) = Generated_Clicks


         'Find a random space based upon the "running" avg. and desired deviation
         'Make sure it between the min and max required.
         Do
             ' Generate a random number between -1 and 1
            SignChanger = Rnd() - Rnd()

            ' Apply the randomized StdDev
            NoClickDays_Deviation = NoClickDays_Desired_Deviation * SignChanger


            'Figure out the "running" average
            NoClickDaysPerClick_Running_Avg = NoClickDays_Remaining / RemainingClickedDays

            'Figure out a space value and round to the nearest whole number
            Generated_NoClickDays = Round(NoClickDaysPerClick_Running_Avg + NoClickDays_Deviation, 0)

        ' Make sure it meets the requirements, if not, try again
        Loop While Generated_NoClickDays < NoClickDays_Min Or Generated_NoClickDays >= NoClickDays_Max



        'Define the array index based upon the spacing previously generated.
        ' Make sure to "add" upon the already known index. Add 1 because you
        'have to account for the index the click occupies
        ClickOffset = ClickOffset + Generated_NoClickDays + 1




        'These should be self-explaintory
        ClickedDaysSoFar = ClickedDaysSoFar + 1
        Clicks_SoFar = Clicks_SoFar + Generated_Clicks
        NoClickDays_SoFar = NoClickDays_SoFar + Generated_NoClickDays

    Loop While ClickOffset < Total_Days And RemainingClickedDays > 0



    'Set the array equal to the clicks so that it returns the array as
    'we want. Ideally this will be just replace Total_Days fields under
    'the base, so not to require a array-function. Neither of these work:
    'ClickSpacer = Range("P1:P" & UBound(Day_Array) + 1).Value
    'Range("P1:P" & UBound(Day_Array) + 1) = Application.Transpose(Day_Array)


    ClickSpacer = Day_Array



End Function
```

Comment: There's a *lot* of code lines that are commented out here. Is your delete key broken?

Comment: Sorry, a lot of the variables beings Dim but commented out is because they are defined as function parameters, but I still comment them so I know they are defined and I have 1 place where everything is defined (not everything is defined as a Dim yet...its a WIP)

Comment: But then why make the readers here go through that, errr, excessive noise and excessive whitespace? Scrollbars are not a good sign...!

Comment: @BHare: Why do you dimension variables that are already declared as function parameters? You mean you do it just so that you can *tell* they're already defined? That's nuts—look at the function parameter. You don't *need* one place where everything is defined. In fact, you actually don't want it. You should keep your variables declared within the smallest scope possible. Dim'ing everything at the top of a function is so old school it's not even cool.

Comment: I guess your right, I took out the commented Dims... All the other comments are to help explain whats going on though.

Comment: Well, *all* the other comments ;-) (The following would not get you hired in my company: *Set the obvious defaults*, *These should be self-explaintory* and *Give the ClickOffset a starting value*.) What's up with the *empty* lines? The scrollbars are still there!

Comment: Id rather over comment than under-comment. Plus the VBA will be visible but non-coding people if they want to change it

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumption is correct. The "problem" with the code you have above is that it uses StdDev as the basis for generating random numbers, so the standard deviation will tend to be accurate and the mean will be less accurate.

If you want more accuracy with the mean and less with the standard deviation, then you'll have to "flip" how numbers are generated: they'll need to center around your desired mean and use the desired standard deviation as a guide, rather than the other way around.

I have an idea about how this can be done, but it will take more concentration than I can apply at work, so I'll have to come back and edit this later. I'll see what I can do.